# How to convert micro to milliseconds in one column and aggregate mode of another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with 2 columns. One is the timestamp in microseconds and the other is a a value. It looks like this:

```
         time  score
        83620      4
        83621      4
        83622      4
        83623      4
        83624      4
        83625      4
        83626      4
        83627      4
        83628      4
        83629      4
        83630      4
        83631      4
        83632      4
        83633      5
        83634      5
        83635      5
        83636      5
        83637      5
        83638      5
        83639      6
        83640      1
        83641      1
        83642      4
```

I want to concert df.time to milliseconds and aggregate df.score by the mode. It should look like this:

```
         time  score
        8362      4
        8363      5
        8364      1
```

Comment: Convert micro to milli means drop three digits, not one. Divide /1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(df['time'] // 10)['score'].apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

Output:

```
time
8362    4
8363    5
8364    1
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1. Using resample, but I have only learned about it today and have not tried it so far, but it looks powerful.
   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html
2. My favorite way to do this:

```
df["milliseconds"] = np.round(df["time"] / 1000, 0) # For cutoff, consider // 1000
df = df.groupby("milliseconds").agg(score=("score", "mode")).reset_index()
```

If time-critical, consider doing the millisecond calculation with .apply() or with list-comprehension. If you do it with apply, remember that lambda functions have an overhead.
For very large samples, numpy will probably be slightly faster.
Resample will probably be faster than grouping, but this is quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert time column so it contains milliseconds. 1 microsecond contains 0.001 milliseconds. Therefore, this code will convert your time column to milliseconds:

```
df['time'] = df['time'] / 1000
```

Then, group by the desired column, in this case score, and then specify that you was time column aggregated by mode. This can be done using the following code:

```
df.groupby(['score']).apply(pd.DataFrame.mode).reset_index(drop=True)
```